# Error in deploy stage: "lchmod (file attributes) error: Not supported"

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud

I am attempting to deploy an image "casbin-role-backend" to cloud, but it always failed.

The following is found from log:

```
Preparing to start the job...
Pipeline image: latest
Preparing the build artifacts...
lchmod (file attributes) error: Not supported
.....
DEPLOYING using manifest
+++ kubectl apply --namespace default -f ./tmp.deployment.yaml
deployment.apps/casbin-role-backend unchanged
The Service "casbin-role-backend" is invalid: spec.ports[0].nodePort: Invalid value: 30080: provided port is already allocated
+++ set +x
CHECKING deployment rollout of casbin-role-backend

+++ kubectl rollout status deploy/casbin-role-backend --watch=true --timeout=150s --namespace default
error: deployment "casbin-role-backend" exceeded its progress deadline
+++ STATUS=fail
+++ set +x
SHOWING last events
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON                 OBJECT                                     MESSAGE
41m         Warning   Failed                 pod/casbin-role-mgt-ui-7d59b6d4cf-2pbhm    Error: InvalidImageName
2m11s       Warning   InspectFailed          pod/casbin-role-backend-68d76464dd-vbvch   Failed to apply default image tag "//:": couldn't parse image reference "//:": invalid reference format
```

...
DEPLOYMENT FAILED
....
OK

```
Finished: FAILED
```

And below is my deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: casbin-role-backend
  labels:
    app: app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    name: http
    nodePort: 30080
  selector:
    app: app
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: casbin-role-backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: casbin-role-backend
        image: xxx/casbin-role-backend
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
```

Does anybody know what error is it? I had searched it for some time but still cannot find what is it and how to fix.

Update:
The source code is originated from below, and I added Dockerfile and deployment.yaml to deploy it on k8s.
https://github.com/alikhan866/Casbin-Role-Mgt-Dashboard-RBAC

Dockerfile source:

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /dist

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

# add app
COPY . ./

# start app
CMD ["npm", "run dev"]
```

Comment: Based on a quick Internet search it seems like a problem with your base image. Could you provide more details on the actual container / image you would to deploy?

Comment: Please publish the source code of casbin-role-backend image, or it's not easy to help here.

Comment: Thanks all, i had updated the details and code above

Comment: Sorry if that sound obvious but Is the `xxx` from `image: xxx/casbin-role-backend` a placeholder? Could you only share the beginning of it without showing the whole image name?

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues here:

1.

```
The Service "casbin-role-backend" is invalid: spec.ports[0].nodePort: Invalid value: 30080: provided port is already allocated
```

It means that the port used by the `nodePort` service is already in use. You can list these services with: `kubectl get svc --all-namespaces | grep '30080'` and change the port value or delete the service. Also, make sure that you specify the proper namespace.

2.

```
2m11s       Warning   InspectFailed          pod/casbin-role-backend-68d76464dd-vbvch   Failed to apply default image tag "//:": couldn't parse image reference "//:": invalid reference format`
```

My educated guess here is that your image name is invalid because it starts with `https://` or `://`. A proper image name should look like this:

```
image: repository:organization_name/image_name:image_version
```